# Error 504 when reloading PHP page

Tags: php, nginx

I have an old ticket system in production (10+ years old PHP code). Out of the blue started to get 504 errors when replying.

The thing is, the message and/or attachment is posted in the ticket but then for some reason when the system tries to reload the ticket to show the reply, it gets 504.

Checked the logs and get:

```
2017/10/26 21:05:15 [error] 4220#0: *135 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: nosession in /xxx/init.php on line 189
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: login_email in /xxx/init.php on line 212
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: user in /xxx/init.php on line 212
...
```

Lines 212 and 213:

```
$id=$_POST['login_email'] ? $_POST['login_email']:$_SESSION['user']['id'];
$pass=$_POST['login_ticket'] ? $_POST['login_ticket']:$_SESSION['user']['pass'];
```

Another line with the error:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user']['warn'])) { $warn = $_SESSION['user']['warn']; unset($_SESSION['user']['warn']); }
```

I think the session management got somehow affected (undefined variable nosession) present here:

```
if (!$nosession) {
 session_start();
}
```

(Could not find it anywhere in the script file)

and then when the program wants to get some data from the session it keeps looping until the timeout is reached.

Dont know how to verify this, any ideas?

PHP: 5.6.30, nginx 1.6

Thanks!

edit:

```
var_dump(_SESSION)

array(2) { ["user"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(5) "someuser" ["pass"]=> string(32) "xxx" ["type"]=> string(5) "admin" } ["view"]=> array(6) { ["status"]=> string(4) "open" ["sort"]=> string(9) "timestamp" ["way"]=> string(3) "ASC" ["orderby"]=> string(21) "tickets.timestamp ASC" ["per"]=> string(2) "50" ["p"]=> int(1) } }
```

Comment: You could try `var_dump($_SESSION);` just before `Lines 212` to verify what's in the `SESSION` or if its even started.

Comment: Tried to do $some = var_dump($_SESSION);
echo "<script>console.log('$some');</script>"; and get nothing in console.

Comment: I dont belive you can asign `var_dump` to a variable. It will print every thing to the page directly. Like a echo. You need to access the page directly to see this. Is the PHP acting as an API for something like Angular?

Comment: Got the dump, edited my reply with the new info!

Answer (score -1):

This was an issue with updated packages. Dont know which was the culprit but had to revert to an old image of the website and update the database to make it work.